# how to open Xcode project on a pc

Tags: xcode

Hey, I was trying to send my application to a friend, who happens to have a pc. I tried sending the debug file of my project to myself first to see if just my project would open not all of Xcode and interface builder... It worked.

I then tried the same thing with my friend twice, one was sent normally and the other one I zipped before sending.. My friend cant open either.

Is there any way I can make it so my friend can open and view it, can use it so to speak.. (like I have a few buttons that open new nswindows, so I'd like for her to see what I'm doing) someone please help... thanks in advanced.

Comment: Does your friend have XCode or some other tool that can be used to debug OSX programs? Code compiled for OSX is cross-platform to Windows, so probably the best your friend can hope for is look at source code. You might have better luck re-writing the UI code in a cross-platform library like Qt or something.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry Xcode only works on a Mac running OSX. You could ask them to come over or use a remote login.

Answer (score 0):

An **XCODE project** can be opened by various tools like  [SUBLIME](http://www.sublimetext.com/)  and I personally use it for code review in **windows**. Try this..

Answer (score 0):

you can use Notepad ++ .
Download it from [here](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v7.5.4.html)